# R: How do I display clustered matrix heatmap (similar color patterns are grouped)

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I searched a lot of questions about heatmap throughout the site and packages, but I still have a problem.

I have clustered data (kmeans/EM/DBscan..), and I want to create a heatmap by grouping the same cluster. I want the similar color patterns to be grouped in the heatmap, so generally, it looks like a block-diagonal. 
I tried to order the data by the cluster number and display it,

```
k = kmeans(data, 3)
d = data.frame(data)
d = data.frame(d, k$cluster)
d = d[order(d$k.cluster),]
heatmap(as.matrix(d))
```

but it is still not sorted and looks like this link:[image] 
But, I want it to be sorted by its cluster number and looked like this:[image]
Can I do this in R?
I searched lots of packages and tried many ways, but I still have a problem.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't use a red-green colour scheme unless you want to make it impossible to red for the 5-10% of men who have red-green colour weakness.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this using `reshape2` and `ggplot2` as follows:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

# Create dummy data
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
        a = sample(1:5, 1000, replace=TRUE),
        b = sample(1:5, 1000, replace=TRUE),
        c = sample(1:5, 1000, replace=TRUE)
)

# Perform clustering
k <- kmeans(df, 3)

# Append id and cluster
dfc <- cbind(df, id=seq(nrow(df)), cluster=k$cluster)

# Add idsort, the id number ordered by cluster 
dfc$idsort <- dfc$id[order(dfc$cluster)]
dfc$idsort <- order(dfc$idsort)

# use reshape2::melt to create data.frame in long format
dfm <- melt(dfc, id.vars=c("id", "idsort"))

ggplot(dfm, aes(x=variable, y=idsort)) + geom_tile(aes(fill=value))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is precisely what I am trying to do. I realize this question is a little old, but does anyone know how to display the y-axis labels (Probeset.ID) from the OP's question? Thanks.

Comment: How do we use kmeans for something like this df <- data.frame(
        a = sample(c("A","B","C","D","E"), 1000, replace=TRUE),
        b = sample(c("A","B","C","D","E"), 1000, replace=TRUE),
        c = sample(1:5, 1000, replace=TRUE)
)?

Comment: I wish I could assign the green check to this one :-/

Answer (score 2):

You should set `Rowv` and `Colv` to `NA` if you don't want the dendrograms and the subseuent ordering. BTW, You should also put of the scaling. Using the df of Andrie :

```
heatmap(as.matrix(df)[order(k$cluster),],Rowv=NA,Colv=NA,scale="none",labRow=NA)
```

[image]

In fact, this whole heatmap is based on `image()`. You can hack away using `image` to construct a plot exactly like you want. Heatmap is using layout() internally, so it will be diffucult to set the margins. With image you could do eg :

```
myHeatmap <- function(x,ord,xlab="",ylab="",main="My Heatmap",
                      col=heat.colors(5), ...){
    op <- par(mar=c(3,0,2,0)+0.1)
    on.exit(par(op))
    nc <- NCOL(x)
    nr <- NROW(x)
    labCol <- names(x)

    x <- t(x[ord,])
    image(1L:nc, 1L:nr, x, xlim = 0.5 + c(0, nc), ylim = 0.5 +
        c(0, nr), axes = FALSE, xlab=xlab, ylab=ylab, main=main,
        col=col,...)

    axis(1, 1L:nc, labels = labCol, las = 2, line = -0.5, tick = 0)
    axis(2, 1L:nr, labels = NA, las = 2, line = -0.5, tick = 0)
}

library(RColorBrewer)
myHeatmap(df,order(k$cluster),col=brewer.pal(5,"BuGn"))
```

To produce a plot that has less margins on the side. You can also manipulate axes, colors, ... You should definitely take a look at the `RColorBrewer`package

(This custom function is based on the internal plotting used by heatmap btw, simplified for the illustration and to get rid of all the dendrogram stuff)

[image]