# Error with ggplot after clustering with kmeans

Tags: r, ggplot2, k-means

I found this previously published Q&A:
[R: How do I display clustered matrix heatmap (similar color patterns are grouped)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687891/r-how-do-i-display-clustered-matrix-heatmap-similar-color-patterns-are-grouped)

However, when trying to do the same with my data I get:
[ggplot Heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8uKd.png)
My code is:

```
Data <- X
Data.features <-Data
Data.features$condition <-NULL
results <- kmeans(Data.features, 12)
m2 <- cbind(Data.features, id=seq(nrow(Data.features)), Data$condition, results$cluster)
m2$idsort <- m2$`Data$condition`[order(m2$`results$cluster`)]
m2$idsort <- order(m2$idsort)
library(reshape2)
m3 <- melt(m2, id.vars = c("id", "idsort"))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(m3, aes(x=variable, y=idsort)) + geom_tile(aes(fill=value))
```

Here is the beginning of the m3:

```
 id idsort  variable    value   
1   1   BV  RM  1.488831956
2   2   BV  RM  -0.060080659
3   3   BV  RM  -0.965135718
4   4   BV  RM  0.109121125
5   5   BV  RM  0.529575031
6   6   BV  RM  0.345320036
7   7   BV  RM  -0.130297731
8   8   Nun RM  -0.352261118
9   9   BV  RM  -1.076270641
10  10  BV  RM  -0.35698175
11  11  BV  RM  0.986731511
12  12  BV  RM  0.442295651
13  13  un  RM  0.74754209
14  14  un  RM  -0.535263676
15  15  un  RM  -0.61017644
16  16  cF  RM  -1.476832822
17  17  Bw  RM  0.031005185
18  18  Bw  RM  -0.368904758
19  19  cF  RM  -1.788968277
20  20  cF  RM  -1.828974127
21  21  cF  RM  -2.22952264
22  22  cF  RM  1.444215761
23  23  Bw  RM  0.624473691
24  24  un  RM  0.593635853
25  25  un  RM  0.388536217
26  26  Nun RM  0.348805061
27  27  NcF RM  -0.899908037
28  28  NcF RM  0.828383186
29  29  NcF RM  0.499278949
30  30  un  RM  2.316891992
31  31  Nun RM  -1.216437876
32  32  BV  RM  0.18346742
33  33  un  RM  -0.057088997
34  34  BV  RM  -1.486598664
35  35  NBV RM  -0.31906404
36  36  BV  RM  0.379173977
37  37  BV  RM  -1.067540594
38  38  BV  RM  0.876030348
39  39  BV  RM  1.263694633
40  40  cF  RM  -0.716306437
```

I can't find my mistake. 
Would appreciate any suggestion.
Thank you.

Comment: Without an extract of your data it is not possible to say. We cannot test your statements nor guess at what might be wrong. If you could supply even a short extract of the m3 dataframe it would help us to help you.

Comment: What happens if you do:  `fill = as.numeric(value)`?

Comment: That works  @Juan, perfect, thank you. I'm trying to understand what does fill = as.numeric do? if the values are numeric?

Comment: Probably, in some step of wrangling your data, the value columns changed its type from numeric to something else, even if it looks like numeric data.
Try `str(m3)` to check what type is each of its columns.

Comment: @Juan, yes it appears as chr...