# Plot a tree diagram from a list in R

Tags: r, plot, visualization

I have a decision tree represented as a list in R:

```
tree = list(
    "Bin type" = list(
        "no bin" = list(
            "SOA linearity" = list(
                "linear" = list("Linear MEM")
                , "non-linear" = list("GAMM")
            )
        )
        , "bin" = list(
            "SOA type" = list(
                "SOA as categorical" = list(
                    "Tool" = list(
                        "ANOVA"
                        , "MEM"
                    )
                )
                , "SOA as continuous" = list(
                    "SOA linearity" = list(
                        "linear" = list(
                            "Tool" = list(
                                "ANOVA"
                                , "MEM"
                            )
                        )
                        , "non-linear" = list("GAMM")
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Is there a quick way to visualize this as a tree diagram?

Comment: haven't used it, but http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggdendro/index.html may be worth looking at. Note, @andrie is the maintainer of the package

Comment: no luck, ggdendro plots trees resulting from fitting algorithms like hclust, kmeans, etc. I don't see a simple way to plot a tree from a list.

Comment: You might a look at @Iselzer's answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673162/reproducing-lattice-dendrogram-graph-with-ggplot2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an immediate way, since packages for plotting trees would want a specific data structure for the tree which would unlikely match your list.  So likely you'll need to convert your list into another form.

I would look at the [igraph](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/igraph/index.html) package.  I'd start with the `graph()` function; if you could convert your list (describing a tree) to a graph, the `igraph` package would help you to plot it.