# How can I obtain an 'unbalanced' grid of ggplots?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid

With `grid.arrange` I can arrange multiple `ggplot` figures in a grid to achieve a multi-panel figure by using something like:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
```

generate some ggplot2 plots , then

```
plot5 <- grid.arrange(plot4, plot1, heights=c(3/4, 1/4), ncol=1, nrow=2)
```

How can I obtain an 'unbalanced' 2 col layout with one plot in the entire first col and three plots in the second col? 
I toyed with a 'grid-of-grids' approach by trying to use `grid.arrange` to plot one grid (e.g. `plot5`, above) against another plot, but obtained:

> Error in arrangeGrob(..., as.table = as.table, clip = clip, main = main,  : 
>             input must be grobs!

**Update:**

Thanks for the advice. I will look into `viewports` and `grid`. In the meantime, thanks to @DWin, the `layOut` function in the 'wq' package worked very well for the compilation figure in my `Sweave` document:
[image]

**Update 2:**

The `arrangeGrob`command (as suggested by @baptiste) also works well, and seems very intuitive - at least it was easy to alter widths of the two columns. It also has the benefit of not requiring the `wq' package.

e.g. Here is the code from my Sweave file:

```
<<label=fig5plot, echo=F, results=hide>>=
plot5<-grid.arrange(plot4, arrangeGrob(plot1, plot2, plot3, ncol=1), 
                    ncol=2, widths=c(1,1.2))
@
\begin{figure}[]
    \begin{center}
<<label=fig5,fig=TRUE,echo=T, width=10,height=12>>=
<<fig5plot>>
@
\end{center}
\caption{Combined plots using the `arrangeGrob' command.}
\label{fig:five}
\end{figure}
```

which produces the following output:
[image]

BTW, Anyone tell me why the '>NA' appears?

Comment: You might have to set up the viewports yourself -- `grid.arrange` might not be flexible enough (search stackoverflow for "[r] grid viewport")

Comment: @BenBolker Has pointed you in a fruitful direction using `grid`.  See also Hadley's ggplot2 book, Section 8.4.2.

Comment: @BenBolker `grid.arrange` can be used with nested viewports using its companion `arrangeGrob` (essentially returning a `gTree`), as in the example I gave below.

Comment: your final assignment to `plot5` is not required as `grid.arrange` returns nothing (NULL). If you want to save the resulting grob use `arrangeGrob` again (and `grid.draw` to display it).

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`grid.arrange` draws directly on the device; if you want to combine it with other grid objects you need `arrangeGrob`, as in

```
 p = rectGrob()
 grid.arrange(p, arrangeGrob(p,p,p, heights=c(3/4, 1/4, 1/4), ncol=1),
              ncol=2)
```

*Edit* (07/2015): with v>2.0.0 you can use the `layout_matrix` argument,

```
 grid.arrange(p,p,p,p, layout_matrix = cbind(c(1,1,1), c(2,3,4)))
```

Comment: Could you explain how the ```cbind(c(1,1,1), c(2,3,4))``` matrix describes the arrangement of the figures?

Comment: @RonGejman it's easy if you print the 3x2 matrix on screen: first column is all 1s, that's where the first plot lives, spanning the three rows; second column contains plots 2, 3, 4, each occupying one row.

Answer (score 18):

I tried figuring it out with grid and thought I had it down but ended up failing (although looking now at the code in the function I cite below, I can see that I was really close ... :-)

The 'wq' package has a `layOut` function that will do it for you:

```
p1 <- qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars)
layOut(list(p1, 1:3, 1),   # takes three rows and the first column
        list(p1, 1, 2),    # next three are on separate rows
         list(p1, 2,2), 
          list(p1, 3,2))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that is a useful function! I think copy+paste may have failed you, though; did you mean for `g1`, `g2`, etc to all be `p1`?

Comment: @joran: I did. I can't remember which of the "three virtues of programming" is Laziness, but I know that is is there somewhere.

Comment: Thanks! Worked very nicely. See above.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative is the [`patchwork`](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork) package by Thomas Lin Pedersen.

```
# install.packages("devtools")
# devtools::install_github("thomasp85/patchwork")
library(patchwork)
```

Generate some plots.

```
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(mpg, disp)) + facet_grid(rows = vars(gear))
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_boxplot(aes(gear, disp, group = gear))
p3 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_smooth(aes(disp, qsec))
p4 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_bar(aes(carb))
```

Now arrange the plots.

```
p1 + (p2 / p3 / p4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is also [multipanelfigure package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multipanelfigure/vignettes/panel-positioning.html) that is worth to mention. See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51220506/786542).

```r
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())

q1 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(mpg, disp))
q2 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_boxplot(aes(gear, disp, group = gear))
q3 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_smooth(aes(disp, qsec))
q4 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_bar(aes(carb))

library(magrittr)
library(multipanelfigure)

figure1 <- multi_panel_figure(columns = 2, rows = 3, panel_label_type = "upper-roman")

figure1 %<>%
  fill_panel(q1, column = 1, row = 1:3) %<>%
  fill_panel(q2, column = 2, row = 1) %<>%
  fill_panel(q3, column = 2, row = 2) %<>%
  fill_panel(q4, column = 2, row = 3)
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
figure1
```

[image]

Created on 2018-07-16 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using the [plot_grid](https://wilkelab.org/cowplot/articles/plot_grid.html) function from the [cowplot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html) package. To create nested grid plots, you can combine multiple `plot_grid` to show multiple plots with different grids. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

# plots
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) + 
  geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(carb)) +
  geom_bar()
p3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = NULL, y = disp)) + 
  geom_boxplot()

# Left column with two plots
left_col <- plot_grid(p1, p2, ncol = 1)
# Combine leff_col with third plot
plot_grid(left_col, p3, ncol = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

As you can see in the example, plot 1 and 2 are from one grid combined with p3 which give the current result. You can modify this to whatever you want.