# Is it possible to create a multiplot of data and images with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to know if it is possible with ggplot2 to create a multiple plot (like a facet) including images to look like that:

[image: What I would like]

I don't know exactly how to arrange the image data to pass them to `geom_raster()` or how to include an image in a data frame...

what I have tried:

```
> img1 <- readPNG('1.png')
> img2 <- readPNG('2.png')
> img3 <- readPNG('3.png')

> test <- data.frame(c(1,2,3),c(5,2,7),c(img1,img2,img3))
> nrow(test)
 [1] 4343040
```

I already have a problem here to build a data frame with the images inside... each 3 lines a repeated (I guess once per pixel).

Comment: It is possible, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @zx8754 I have been able to reads the images with `readPNG`, and tried to make a vector of several images and include that in a data frame with some numbers. This did not work very well, I have tried to add 3 rows but end up with a data frame with millions of rows. Then I guess I will need to use `geom_raster()` to print the images and in the example above `geom_point()` but I don't see how to select the columns for `facet_grid()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I went finally with this solution which decompose the plot to a gtable, add one more line and insert images. Of course once decompose one can't add more layer to the plot, so it should be the very last operation. I don't think the gtable can be converted back to plot.

```
library(png)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)
library(RCurl) # just to load image from URL

#Loading images
img0 <- readPNG(getURLContent('https://i.stack.imgur.com/3anUH.png'))
img1 <- readPNG(getURLContent('https://i.stack.imgur.com/3anUH.png'))

#Convert images to Grob (graphical objects)
grob0 <- rasterGrob(img0)
grob1 <- rasterGrob(img1)

# create the plot with data
p <- ggplot(subset(mpg,manufacturer=='audi'|manufacturer=='toyota'),aes(x=cty,y=displ))+facet_grid(year~manufacturer)+geom_point()

# convert the plot to gtable
mytable <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))

#Add a line ssame height as line 4 after line 3
# use gtable_show_layout(mytable) to see where you want to put your line
mytable <- gtable_add_rows(mytable, mytable$height[[4]], 3)
# if needed mor row can be added 
# (for example to keep consistent spacing with other graphs)

#Insert the grob in the cells of the new line
mytable <- gtable_add_grob(mytable,grob0,4,4, name = paste(runif(1)))
mytable <- gtable_add_grob(mytable,grob1,4,6, name = paste(runif(1)))

#rendering
grid.draw(mytable)
```

[image: Result]

Note: In this example, I use twice the same image, but it is of course possible to have as much as needed.

Inspired by: [How do you add a general label to facets in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353287/how-do-you-add-a-general-label-to-facets-in-ggplot2)

Comment: I'd agree that this is a more elegant solution to your original question. :) The `gtable` package looks neat.

Answer (score 3):

This a rather peculiar question. Normally probably it's faster to "photoshop" one than rastering the plots into images etc (I meant, measured by how much human effort it takes).

But since your question has a fun component in it, below I provide one shoddy solution.
The starting point is the example you provided. I use some R code to extract the two faces, and then combine them with two plots (any plots). The plots will be saved to PNG, and then loaded into R as a rastered image.

Eventually you combine the four facets and make one final plot.

```
library(png)
library(ggplot2)

# load PNG file, and reduce dimension to 1. 
# there's no sanity check to verify how many channels a PNG file has.
# potentially there can be 1 (grayscale), 3 (RGB) and 4 (RGBA).
# Here I assume that PNG file f has 4 channels.
load_png <- function(f) {
  d <- readPNG(f)
  # CCIR 601

  rgb.weights <- c(0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140)
  grayscale <- matrix(apply(d[,,-4], -3, 
                            function(rgb) rgb %*% rgb.weights), 
                      ncol=dim(d)[2], byrow=T)
  grayscale
}

# the image you provided as an example,
# used to extract the two emoicons
img <- load_png("3anUH.png")

# convert a grayscale matrix into a data.frame,
# facilitating plotting by ggplot
melt_grayscale <- function(d) {
  w <- ncol(d)
  h <- nrow(d)
  coords <- expand.grid(1:w, 1:h)
  df <- cbind(coords, as.vector(d))
  names(df) <- c("x", "y", "gs")
  # so that smallest Y is at the top
  df$y <- h - df$y + 1

  df
}

plot_grayscale <- function(d, melt=F) {
  df <- melt_grayscale(d)
  ggplot(df) + geom_raster(aes(x=x, y=y, fill=gs)) + scale_fill_continuous(low="#000000", high="#ffffff")
}

ggplot_blank <- function(x, y) {
  # to plot a graph without any axis, grid and legend
  # otherwise it would look weird when performing facet_wrap()

  qplot(x, y + rnorm(10), size=15) + 
    theme(axis.line=element_blank(),
          axis.text.x=element_blank(),
          axis.text.y=element_blank(),
          axis.ticks=element_blank(),
          axis.title.x=element_blank(),
          axis.title.y=element_blank(),
          legend.position="none",
          panel.background=element_blank(),
          panel.border=element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
          plot.background=element_blank())
}

# extract the two faces
#offset <- c(50, 40)

img0 <- img[50:200, 40:190]
img1 <- img[210:360, 40:190]

plot_grayscale(img0)
plot_grayscale(img1)
```

At this point we have `img0` that looks like: [image: img0].

You can probably adjust the subsetting offset to getting a cleaner cut.

Next we want to draw two plots, and save the plot to PNGs which can be loaded later.

```
# now plot two PNGs using ggplot
png(file="p0.png", width=150, height=150)
ggplot_blank(1:10, 10:1 + rnorm(10))
dev.off()

png(file="p1.png", width=150, height=150)
ggplot_blank(1:10, rnorm(10, 10))
dev.off()

p0 <- load_png("p0.png")
p1 <- load_png("p1.png")

# combine PNG grayscale matrices together
# into a melted data.frame, but with an extra column to
# identify which panel does this pixel belong to.
combine.plots <- function(l) {
  panel <- 0
  do.call(rbind, lapply(l, function(m){
    panel <<- panel + 1
    cbind(melt_grayscale(m), panel)
  }))
}

plots <- combine.plots(list(img0, img1, p0, p1))
ggplot(plots) + geom_raster(aes(x=x, y=y, fill=gs)) + 
  scale_fill_continuous(low="#000000", high="#ffffff") + facet_wrap(~panel)
```

[image: And, viola, this is the final plot]

Of course the obvious drawback is that you only have grayscale image with above example.
It would be much trickier if you want RGB color in your final plot.

You can probably do what GIF format is doing: indexed color.
Basically you:

- Discretize your RGB values into 256 or 512 colors
- Create a vector of the discretized colors
- Replaces `scale_fill_continous` with `scale_fill_manual` and let `values` equal to the color vector you created above.

## EDIT: Combine `geom_raster` with `geom_point`.

Above solution used `png()` function to first save the plot to a PNG file (involving rasterization), and then loaded the rasterized images into R. This process could potentially lead to resolution loss, if, say, the two images shown in the top panels are themselves of low resolution.

We can modify above solution to combine `geom_point` with `geom_raster`, where the former is used for rendering plots and the latter for rendering images.

The only issue here, (assuming that the two images to display have the same resolution, denoted by `w x h`, where `w` is the width and `h` is the height), is that `facet_wrap` will enforce all panels to have the same X/Y-**limits**. 
So, we need to rescale the plots to the same limits (`w x h`) before plotting them.

Below is the modified R code for combining plots and images:

```
library(png)
library(ggplot2)

load_png <- function(f) {
  d <- readPNG(f)
  # CCIR 601

  rgb.weights <- c(0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140)
  grayscale <- matrix(apply(d[,,-4], -3, 
                            function(rgb) rgb %*% rgb.weights), 
                      ncol=dim(d)[2], byrow=T)
  grayscale
}

# the image you provided as an example,
# used to extract the two emoicons
img <- load_png("3anUH.png")

# convert a grayscale matrix into a data.frame,
# facilitating plotting by ggplot
melt_grayscale <- function(d) {
  w <- ncol(d)
  h <- nrow(d)
  coords <- expand.grid(1:w, 1:h)
  df <- cbind(coords, as.vector(d))
  names(df) <- c("x", "y", "gs")
  df$y <- h - df$y + 1

  df
}

plot_grayscale <- function(d, melt=F) {
  df <- melt_grayscale(d)
  ggplot(df) + geom_raster(aes(x=x, y=y, fill=gs)) + scale_fill_continuous(low="#000000", high="#ffffff")
}

ggplot_blank <- function(x, y) {
  # to plot a graph without any axis, grid and legend
  qplot(x, y + rnorm(10), size=15) + 
    theme(axis.line=element_blank(),
          axis.text.x=element_blank(),
          axis.text.y=element_blank(),
          axis.ticks=element_blank(),
          axis.title.x=element_blank(),
          axis.title.y=element_blank(),
          legend.position="none",
          panel.background=element_blank(),
          panel.border=element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
          plot.background=element_blank())
}

# extract the two faces
#offset <- c(50, 40)

img0 <- img[50:200, 40:190]
img1 <- img[210:360, 40:190]

plot_grayscale(img0)
plot_grayscale(img1)

# now plot two PNGs using ggplot
png(file="p0.png", width=300, height=300)
ggplot_blank(1:10, 10:1 + rnorm(10))
dev.off()

png(file="p1.png", width=300, height=300)
ggplot_blank(1:10, rnorm(10, 10))
dev.off()

p0 <- load_png("p0.png")
p1 <- load_png("p1.png")

combine.plots <- function(l) {
  panel <- 0
  do.call(rbind, lapply(l, function(m){
    panel <<- panel + 1
    cbind(melt_grayscale(m), panel)
  }))
}

rescale.plots <- function(x, y, w, h, panel) {
  # need to rescale plots to the same scale (w x h)
  x <- (x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)) * w
  y <- (y - min(y)) / (max(y) - min(y)) * h

  data.frame(x=x, y=y, panel=panel)
}

imgs <- combine.plots(list(img0, img1))


# combine two plots, with proper rescaling
plots <- rbind(
  rescale.plots(1:100, 100:1 + rnorm(100), 150, 150, panel=3),
  rescale.plots(1:100, rnorm(100), 150, 150, panel=4)
)


ggplot() + geom_raster(data=imgs, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=gs)) + geom_point(data=plots, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  facet_wrap(~panel) + scale_fill_continuous(low="#000000", high="#ffffff")
```

which will give you:

[image: An updated combine plots]

You may not visually detect the immediate difference, but it will be obvious when you resize the output image in R.

Comment: Thanks! It brings me much closer. I want to display fluorescence images this way, so they are basically grayscale, but it would be great to be able to have the 2 different images in different colours. Img0 in 'redscale' and Img1 in 'bluescale' for example. I will play around with that and update if I manage to do it.

Comment: Oh, in that case it is much easier, since you already know the colors you would like to display for `img0` and `img1`. You can discretize the grayscale for the two images, but use different factor levels (*e.g.* `img0` with factor level 1-256, `img1` with 257-512 etc). Then you create your own manual color mapping.

Comment: I didn't realize first, but I see in your solution that you use first export graph to png and then you use geom_raster. This will result in resolution loss by rasterising graph.

Comment: It depends on how much resolution you want for the plot. I used 150 because in the example you've provided, the smiley faces are 150x150. If your florescence images have higher resolution, you can definitely use a larger resolution for the rasterizing. In the end when you call `geom_raster`, the result is a rasterized graph anyway. So what's the concern here?

Comment: If you have a very high resolution florescence images, you can raster the PNGs into the same resolution as well. And if you prefer higher resolution for your plots, you can always rescale your florescence images to such a size that you would feel comfortable with the plots. 

Or, you can generate the plot to a very high resolution, then downscaling the plots to an appropriate size.

Comment: Okay, I've edited my answer to give you an alternative, where you don't necessarily have to rasterize the plots as PNGs.

Comment: Png images are by definition rasterized, no miracle there, but plots are vector graphic, it is always better to keep them as vector as long as possible. If you render the plot at a different aspect ratio the vector version will scale properly while the raster is fixed forever.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I was kind of restraining myself to find the answer in a strict `ggplot2` context. But I've learnt a lot of arranging grids from your answer. Even my edited answer has an obvious flaw: the axis for the plots are completely messed up and non-informative.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using gridExtra to combine a separate plot with the images you want?

For example;

```
# import packages needed
library(png)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

# read image files
img1 <- readPNG('1.png')
img2 <- readPNG('2.png')

# convert images to objects that gridExtra can handle
image1 <- rasterGrob(img1, interpolate=TRUE)
image2 <- rasterGrob(img2, interpolate=TRUE)

# create whatever plot you want under the images;
test <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y =c(5,2,7), facet = c("A", "B", "B"))
plot <- ggplot(test,aes(x=x, y= y)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ facet) 

# use grid.arrange to display the images and the plot on the same output. 
grid.arrange(image1,image2,plot, ncol = 2)
```

You might have to play around a bit with grid.arrange to get the exact output.

```
# perhaps something like:
p = rectGrob()
grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(image1, image2, widths=c(1/2), ncol =2), plot, ncol=1)
```

adapted from an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112208/how-can-i-obtain-an-unbalanced-grid-of-ggplots).

Hope that helps.