# Rectangular ggplot2 geom_point shape

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112208/how-can-i-obtain-an-unbalanced-grid-of-ggplots) which had a really cool graph . I am interested in the graphs on the left with the rectangular points across time.

These rectangular points are not part of R's default set of points to give the geom_point() command. While I can reproduce the graph (or at least one very similar) I don't know how to get the points to look like that.

How can I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that's just `geom_tile`, not `geom_point` in target plot.

```
require("ggplot2")

ggplot(iris) + geom_tile(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, 
                             fill = Petal.Length), color = "white") + 
  facet_grid(Species ~ .) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "red3", high = "blue4")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While not exactly what you are after, you can change the plotting shapes with `scale_shape_manual()` ie

```
d <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species, shape = Species))
d <- d + geom_point()
d + scale_shape_manual(values = c(15, 15, 15))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but `scale_shape_manual()` allows you to set the sequence of shapes used in ggplot but not introduce new shapes (or alter existing ones) which is what I believe I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with geom_rect:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(1,2,1), type = c("a","b","c"))
ggplot(df) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = x, ymin = y, xmax = x + 0.3, ymax = y + 0.6, fill = type))
```