# Automatically adjust plot title width using ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am fairly new to R/ggplot2 and still learning on the go. Hopefully I am not missing something obvious!

I am trying to create several different plots using ggplot2 that I am layouting using the function plot_grid from the cowplot package to make the plots visible side by side and add plot numeration and captions. The problem is that if the generated plots are displayed in a small window or I have many plots beside one another then the titles of the two plots sometimes overlap. To solve this problem I tried to automatically insert line breaks in my too long titles using code I found in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631780/r-ggplot2-can-i-set-the-plot-title-to-wrap-around-and-shrink-the-text-to-fit-t) since I wanted the text size of the titles to stay constant.

Using the following code I can easily automatically insert the necessary line breaks to make my title a specific width, but the problem is that I always need to enter a numeric value for the width. Depending on the number of plots I am inserting this value would of course change. I could of course go through my code and manually set the width for each set of plots until it is the correct value, but I was hoping to automate this process so that the title width is adjusted automatically to match the width of the x-axis. Is there anyway to implement this in R?

```
    #automatically line break and add titles 
    myplot_theme1 = function (plot, x.title = NULL, y.title = NULL, plot.title = NULL) {
        plot +   
        labs(title = paste(strwrap(plot.title, width = 50), collapse = "\n"),
           x = x.title, 
           y = y.title)
    }


    # generate an example plot
    data_plot <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000), y = rnorm (1000))
    plot1 <- ggplot(data_plot, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() 
    title <- "This is a title that is very long and does not display nicely"
    myplot_theme1(plot1, plot.title = title)
```

[My test plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPaLe.png)

I have tried searching but I haven't found any solutions that seem to address what I am looking for. The [only solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867325/get-width-of-plot-area-in-ggplot2) I did find that looked promising was based on the package gridDebug. This packages doesn't seem to be supported by my operating system anymore though (macOS Sierra Version 10.12.6) since when I try to install it I get the following error message:

> Warning in install.packages: dependencies ‘graph’, ‘Rgraphviz’ are not available

And on the [CRAN package documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridDebug/index.html) it states that the package is not even available for macOS El Capitan which was my previous operating system. If someone knows what is causing this issue so that I could try the solution from the above thread that would of course be great as well.

Comment: Did you try to put the plot output inside a ```div```?

Comment: No I haven't. I am not sure what you mean with a div exactly though? I've tried googling it but apparently am not searching in the correct context. A tip where I can find some more information?

Answer (score 0):

One idea (but perhaps not an ideal solution) is to adjust the size of text based on the number of characters in the title. You can adjust `ggplot` properties using `theme` and in this case you want to adjust `plot.title` (the theme property, not your variable). `plot.title` has elements `size` and horizontal justification `hjust`, the latter is in range [0,1].

```
# generate an example plot
data_plot <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000), y = rnorm (1000))
plot1 <- ggplot(data_plot, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() 
title1 <- "This is a title that is very long and does not display nicely"
title2 <- "I'm an even longer sentence just test me out and see if I display the way you want or you'll be sorry"

myplot_theme1 = function (plot, x.title = NULL, y.title = NULL, plot.title = NULL) {
        plot +   
        labs(title = plot.title,
           x = x.title, 
           y = y.title) +
        theme(plot.title = element_text(size=800/nchar(plot.title), hjust=0.5))  # 800 is arbitrarily chosen
    }

myplot_theme1(plot1, plot.title = title1)
myplot_theme1(plot1, plot.title = title2)
```

Comment: Sadly it won't solve my problem since I need the text size to stay constant (the plots are for a report and the figure titles all need to have a standardized text font). Thank you though!

Comment: If your text size must stay the same, you could use a similar idea as above, that is, adjust the width of your plot by some value that depends on the number of characters in your title. Something like `strwrap(plot.title, width = nchar(plot.title)*X)`

Comment: If I don't find another solution I'll do that, its not quite ideal though since it will make some of my plots look stretched out. Maybe someone will have a suggestion how to get the x-axis width.