# "ColSideColors" in heatmap made bye ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

There is a very useful option "ColSideColors" in the native "heatmap" function in R, but how to implement this effect by ggplot2?

As shown in the heatmap, I would like to make the red and blue bar to represent different groups with ggplot2.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reproducing lattice dendrogram  graph with ggplot2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673162/reproducing-lattice-dendrogram-graph-with-ggplot2)

Answer (score 1):

I would say what you are looking for is facetting - in your case you would want to have a factor that distinguishes data entries between the red and the blue part and then have a `facet_grid()` to split up the graph with respective labels. Say your factor is called `subset` in the melted dataframe, you would need to add the following to your plot:

```
facet_grid(. ~ subset)
```

For further details, have a look at the [`facet_grid()` documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/facet_grid.html).

And for an answer that more explicitly addresses your problem, you should describe your problem in more detail. Have a look at some info on [how to produce a great reproducible example in R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2352071).