# Plot horizontal dendrogram with hanging leaves? (R)

Tags: r, dendrogram, hclust, dendextend

I would like to create a dendrogram plot with horizontal labels, but having the leaves hang according to their height, instead of just drop to the edge of the plot.

Example:

```
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave")
plot(hc) # a plot with hanging branches
plot(as.dendrogram(hc), horiz = TRUE) # a horizontal plot, but the branches are not hanging
```

[image]

Any suggestion on how this can be programmed?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can do something close to this using the last example in `?dendrogram`.

Comment: Hi Ferdinand, I admit I don't see how.  Can you expand on your idea?

Comment: Using the the `edgetext` attribute, to be set for every edge using `dendrapply`. It's just an idea, I don't have the time now to pursue this. :-(

Comment: [Have you seen this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673162/reproducing-lattice-dendrogram-graph-with-ggplot2)? It goes over dendograms in `lattice` and `ggplot2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the value of `hang` in the `as.dendrogram` function.

```
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave")
plot(hc)
plot(as.dendrogram(hc, hang=0.02), horiz = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

For the record, I've implemented a `hang.dendrogram` function (in the dendextend package), to allow hanging a dendrogram also after is was created (and not only during the changing from hclust to a dendrogram). Here is how to use it:

```
install.packages("dendextend")
library(dendextend)

dend <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave"))
par(mar = c(5,5,5,5))
plot(hang.dendrogram(dend), horiz = TRUE)
```

[image]