# R: replot heatmap produced with heatmap.2

Tags: r, plot, heatmap, gplots

I store the results returned by heatmap.2 (in gplots library)
like this: `hm <- heatmap.2(M)`

Is it possible to replot the heatmap at a later time like: plot(hm), heatmap(hm)?

Comment: What happens when you try: `plot(hm)` or `heatmap(hm)`?

Comment: plot(hm) produces: Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'

Comment: heatmap(hm)
Error in heatmap(hm) : 'x' must be a numeric matrix

Comment: heatmap,2(hm) Error in heatmap.2(hm) : `x' must be a numeric matrix..
Can't understand why somebody gave a negative vote to the question.. bah..

Comment: `hm <- heatmap.2(M)` doesn't work for me... Try using `ggplot` - see answer by @Andrie [Reproducing lattice dendrogram graph with ggplot2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673162/reproducing-lattice-dendrogram-graph-with-ggplot2)

Comment: I don't think you can replot directly a saved `heatmap.2` but you can do it bit by bit: look at `str(hm)` to get an idea of where are the different informations you need (`plot(hm$rowDendrogram)` will plot the tree for instance and `image(hm$carpet)` will plot the heatmap itself).