# pheatmap cluster annotation

Tags: r, heatmap

I am trying to display the result of a clustering algorithm based on k-means as `pheatmap`. For this, I use the procedure suggested here: [R draw kmeans clustering with heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084077/r-draw-kmeans-clustering-with-heatmap)

Now the problem is, that I would like to add a color scheme highlighting the clusters, something similar to the "RowSideColors"-option in `heatmap` and `heatmap.2`. As to `pheatmap`, I found only the `annotation` option, but this works columnwise instead of rowwise. Is there a way to highlight the row clusters in `pheatmap`?

Another idea that I had is to add the cluster-column as a separate color within the heatmap. However, I would need to use another colour scheme than for the rest of the heatmap, so I am not sure if it's possible.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am looking for the exact same thing!

Comment: @Lilith-Elina Unfortunately I haven't find a solution.

Comment: Too bad. :-( I don't understand why pheatmap only annotates columns!

Comment: You may check the [**ComplexHeatmap**](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/html/ComplexHeatmap.html) package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now there is an annotation_row parameter in [pheatmap](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pheatmap/index.html) package:

```
library(pheatmap)

# define a matrix
test = matrix(rnorm(200), 20, 10)
test[1:10, seq(1, 10, 2)] = test[1:10, seq(1, 10, 2)] + 3
test[11:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] = test[11:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] + 2
test[15:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] = test[15:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] + 4
colnames(test) = paste("Test", 1:10, sep = "")
rownames(test) = paste("Gene", 1:20, sep = "")

# annotate rows
annotation_row = data.frame(
GeneClass = factor(rep(c("Path1", "Path2", "Path3"), c(10, 4, 6))))
rownames(annotation_row) = paste("Gene", 1:20, sep = "")

# plot pheatmap
pheatmap(test, annotation_row = annotation_row)
```